# React framework. Object destructuring is not working

Tags: javascript, reactjs, web, web-frontend, react-fullstack

I have a homepage where 3 cards are shown. When a specific card is clicked then the image will show. Now I can change the route but I am not able  to show image and heading. Because all it is saying is destructuring undefined. The console log is showing the JSON data though.

Here is parent component:

```js
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
import DetailsOfDestination from "../DetailsOfDestination/DetailsOfDestination";
import FakeData from "../Fakedata/FakeData";

const PlaceDetail = (props) => {
  const [info, setInfo] = useState(FakeData);
  const { heading, img, text } = props.place;
  return (
    <div>
      {info.map((singleInfo) => (
        <DetailsOfDestination singleInfo={singleInfo}></DetailsOfDestination>
      ))}
      <Link to={`/DetailsOfDestination`}>
        <img src={img} alt="" />
      </Link>
    </div>
  );
};

export default PlaceDetail;
```

Here is child component:

```js
import React from "react";

const DetailsOfDestination = (props) => {
  console.log(props.singleInfo);
  const { heading, img } = props.singleInfo;
  //console.log(heading);
  return (
    <div>
      <h1>{heading}</h1>
    </div>
  );
};

export default DetailsOfDestination;
```

My Fake Data:

```js
const data = [
  {
    img: "https://i.ibb.co/pxgYz0b/Group-1333.png",
    heading: "Cox Bazar",
    text: "Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industrys standard dummy text ever since the 1500s,",
  },
  {
    img: "https://i.ibb.co/3dLyGVd/Group-1335.png",
    heading: "Sreemangal",
    text: "Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industrys standard dummy text ever since the 1500s,",
  },
  {
    img: "https://i.ibb.co/qkHmMFD/Group-1337.png",
    heading: "Sundarban",
    text: "Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industrys standard dummy text ever since the 1500s,",
  },
];

export default data;
```

I'm getting an [error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YUJdC.png). It says:

> "Cannot destructure property `heading` of `props.singleInfo` as it is undefined"

Comment:  Please post code, errors, sample data or textual output here as plain-text, not as images that can be hard to read, can’t be copy-pasted to help test code or use in answers, and are barrier to those who depend on screen readers. You can edit your question to add the code in the body of your question. For easy formatting use the `{}` button to mark blocks of code, or indent with four spaces for the same effect. The contents of a **screenshot can’t be searched, run as code, or copied and edited to create a solution.**

Comment: It looks like the thing you're trying to destructure is `undefined`. What if you put `debugger` there and have a closer look?

Comment: hi just show the fakedata json

Comment: Use const {heading, img } = {...props.singleInfo}.

Answer (score 1):

Without seeing the data - its hard to tell, but my guess is that heading and img are properties of hte singleInfo object that is passed through props.

If you do not destructure the parent object - you will not have access to its children - so singleInfo is the variable and heading and img are properties of that object - so you need to alter the syntax of hte destructure a little bit.

What this will do is both - give access to the singleInfo destructured object - but will also alias its children as indicated.

```
const { singleInfo , singleInfo: { heading , img} } = props;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use destructuring if you are sure that **heading exists in FakeData** or you can use like this

```
<div>
 { props.singleInfo.heading ? (<h1>{props.singleInfo.heading}</h1>) : null }
</div>
```

PS: I noticed destructuring needs to be modified.

```
const {heading, img } = {...props.singleInfo}
```

Please refer the demo: [Demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/trusting-haibt-oosqv?file=/src/DetailsOfDestination.js)

Comment: isn't this the exact opposite of using destructuring?

Comment: so only I have written **or** you can use this :)

Comment: Would still fail/blow up on `props.singleInfo` being undefined when trying to access `heading`. At least suggest using optional chaining (`props.singleInfo?.heading`) or *something* that null checks.